# Can I use a Netgear WNR2000 v2 as a wireless bridge?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-bridge

I'd like to connect my [WNR2000](http://support.netgear.com/app/products/model/a_id/12168) to my existing wireless network and then connect wired devices to the bridge.

Is this possible? How would I set it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this helps

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-turn-an-old-router-into-a-wireless-bridge/

Comment: Note: v3 is supported. v4 and v5 are not supported currently. see https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Known_incompatible_devices and wait for it to disappear from that list before looking at http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices. The later versions might take a few years, or they may never get support.

Answer (score 1):

http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?s=606f89b4036ba06f716c3c1b247995a7&t=44078&page=2, found this with google hope its what your looking for.